# How can I display the metamask address on the webpage dynamically using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, metamask

I can actually get the address of metamask account but everytime I change the account in metamask the specific component seems not to be rendering again I don't know what to add in array parameter of useEffect so that to reflect changes in my `account` on the webpage without reloading. Here is the `useState` and `useEffect` defined in the `app.js`.

I have already implemented the Metamask connecting functionality.

### JavaScript

```js
const [account, setAccount] = useState(null)        // useState functionality

useEffect(() => {                                   // useEffect functionality
    const getaccount = async()=>{
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method:'eth_accounts'});
      setAccount(accounts[0].toUpperCase())
    }
  
    getaccount();
  }, [])
```

### HTML

```html
return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>First Dapp Application</h1>
        <p>Our account address is: {account ? account:"not connected"}</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but basically, you need to add a listener when there is a change in the accounts with this code on a first page load hook:

```
window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
  setAccount(accounts[0].toUpperCase());
});
```

I'm not an expert with react, but I think you could add another `useEffect()` for initialization purpose like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (accounts) {
        setAccount(accounts[0].toUpperCase());
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: Well... Using only event `window.ethereum.on` without `useeffect()` worked pretty well.. I think using useEffect would be a burden then...  

But i kind of not understand that why does this `useeffect()` made by me didn't worked ..... cuz without array parameter that would be rendering forever... and which must change in rendering without relaoding.... am i getting wrong somewhere...??

Comment: @dammn_man123 I just noticed that the code you provided already have a useEffect with `[]`, seems like you don't need another useEffect. It should work on your useEffect though, did you try it? also adding another useEffect is fine, let's say one is for `connect` action, and another for `listeners`.

Comment: Yeahh!! As I mentioned your solution is totally working (with or without effect or even in side the already present useeffect) But I kind of not get it why is that the logic made by me in the question isn't reflecting changes... I kind of just didn't understood why the webpage isn't reflecting changes without event.... BTW thanks for helping..